# matplotlib navtoolbar doesn't realize in wx 2.9 (Mac OS X)

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib, toolbar

The following piece of code produces a matplotlib NavToolbar2 at the top of a frame as expected when run on wxPython 2.8.x, Python 2.5.4/2.6, Matplotlib 0.99.x.

However, I've recently moved to Python 2.7, and wxPython 2.9.1 in an attempt to support OS X in 64-bit. It's under this environment that the code below produces an empty toolbar:

[image: empty toolbar]

I noticed when building matplotlib that it said something about not needing WxAgg for wx 2.9 and up, might this be the problem? All I've tried so far is to replace `FigureCanvasWxAgg` with `FigureCanvasWx` and `NavigationToolbar2WxAgg` with `NavigationToolbar2Wx`. No luck.

Any ideas what's going on?

```
import wx
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg, NavigationToolbar2WxAgg
import matplotlib as mpl

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
f = wx.Frame(None)
fig = mpl.figure.Figure()
p = FigureCanvasWxAgg(f, -1, fig)
tb = NavigationToolbar2WxAgg(fig.canvas)
f.SetToolBar(tb)
tb.Realize()
f.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

One more thing... if I replace the NavigationToolbar2WxAgg with my own custom navtoolbar class (code at first answer on this thread: [Add new navigate modes in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740988/add-new-navigate-modes-in-matplotlib)), the whole thing crashes unless I remove `tb.Realize()`.

```
2011-05-25 08:21:18.354 Python[48013:60f] *** Assertion failure in -[NSToolbar _itemAtIndex:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1038.35/Toolbar.subproj/NSToolbar.m:1227
2011-05-25 08:21:18.356 Python[48013:60f] An uncaught exception was raised
2011-05-25 08:21:18.356 Python[48013:60f] Invalid parameter not satisfying: index>=0 && index<[self _numberOfItems]
2011-05-25 08:21:18.358 Python[48013:60f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: index>=0 && index<[self _numberOfItems]'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff868ef7b4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff83e9b0f3 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff868ef5d7 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 103
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff86d7c77e -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff806f44a9 -[NSToolbar _itemAtIndex:] + 158
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff806f3e94 -[NSToolbar _removeItemAtIndex:notifyDelegate:notifyView:notifyFamilyAndUpdateDefaults:] + 56
    6   libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.1.0.0.dylib    0x0000000101aea2a6 _ZN9wxToolBar7RealizeEv + 1430
    7   _controls_.so                       0x00000001048d4b76 _wrap_ToolBarBase_Realize + 102
    8   .Python                             0x00000001000ca81a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 23498
    9   .Python                             0x00000001000cc8c5 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1733
    10  .Python                             0x00000001000ca9bf PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 23919
    11  .Python                             0x00000001000cc8c5 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1733
    12  .Python                             0x00000001000cb0c8 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25720
    13  .Python                             0x00000001000cc8c5 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1733
    14  .Python                             0x00000001000ca9bf PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 23919
    15  .Python                             0x00000001000cb2a6 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26198
    16  .Python                             0x00000001000cb2a6 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26198
    17  .Python                             0x00000001000cc8c5 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1733
    18  .Python                             0x00000001000ca9bf PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 23919
    19  .Python                             0x00000001000cb2a6 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26198
    20  .Python                             0x00000001000cc8c5 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1733
    21  .Python                             0x00000001000ccbc6 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
    22  .Python                             0x00000001000f0c7e PyRun_FileExFlags + 174
    23  .Python                             0x00000001000f1aa1 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 817
    24  .Python                             0x00000001001093d9 Py_Main + 2825
    25  Python                              0x0000000100000f54 0x0 + 4294971220
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like a bug, but I do not know if the problem lies in matplotlib, in wxPython or in the backend_wx.py. What I did to fix it is that I looked in the [backend_wx.py source code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Python/Chart-Report/Matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.1.1/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_wx.py.htm) for the Toolbar and put it directly in my wxPython toolbar. So this works for me:

```
import os
import wx
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg, NavigationToolbar2WxAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import _load_bitmap
import matplotlib as mpl


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
f = wx.Frame(None)
fig = mpl.figure.Figure()
p = FigureCanvasWxAgg(f, -1, fig)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2WxAgg(p)
toolbar.Hide()

#toolbar constants
TBFLAGS = (wx.TB_HORIZONTAL|wx.TB_TEXT)      
tsize = (24,24)
tb = f.CreateToolBar(TBFLAGS)

_NTB2_HOME = wx.NewId()
_NTB2_BACK = wx.NewId()
_NTB2_FORWARD = wx.NewId()
_NTB2_PAN = wx.NewId()
_NTB2_ZOOM = wx.NewId()
_NTB2_SAVE = wx.NewId()
_NTB2_SUBPLOT = wx.NewId()

tb.AddSimpleTool(_NTB2_HOME, _load_bitmap('home.png'), 'Home', 'Reset original view')
tb.AddSimpleTool(_NTB2_BACK, _load_bitmap('back.png'), 'Back', 'Back navigation view')
tb.AddSimpleTool(_NTB2_FORWARD, _load_bitmap('forward.png'), 'Forward', 'Forward navigation view')

tb.AddCheckTool(_NTB2_PAN, _load_bitmap('move.png'), shortHelp='Pan', longHelp='Pan with left, zoom with right')
tb.AddCheckTool(_NTB2_ZOOM, _load_bitmap('zoom_to_rect.png'), shortHelp='Zoom', longHelp='Zoom to rectangle')

tb.AddSeparator()
tb.AddSimpleTool(_NTB2_SUBPLOT, _load_bitmap('subplots.png'), 'Configure subplots', 'Configure subplot parameters')
tb.AddSimpleTool(_NTB2_SAVE, _load_bitmap('filesave.png'), 'Save', 'Save plot contents to file')

f.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, toolbar.home, id=_NTB2_HOME)
f.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, toolbar.forward, id=_NTB2_FORWARD)
f.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, toolbar.back, id=_NTB2_BACK)
f.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, toolbar.zoom, id=_NTB2_ZOOM)
f.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, toolbar.pan, id=_NTB2_PAN)
f.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, toolbar.configure_subplot, id=_NTB2_SUBPLOT)
f.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, toolbar.save, id=_NTB2_SAVE)

tb.Realize()  

tb.Realize()
f.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

This is a quick fix, but some one has to file a bug report for it I guess.

Comment: Thanks Christoph! Now I see what you meant in your message to me. This is actually pretty nice because I no longer have to deal with the NavigationToolbar2WxAgg. It's a bit of a hack to just hide it, but hey, it works!

Comment: For matplotlib 1.4.3 you need to replace toolbar.configure_subplot with toolbar.configure_subplots and toolbar.save with toolbar.save_figure